# Constraining Text Field to Button in Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, autolayout, uitextfield, nslayoutconstraint

I have a button I created in my storyboard, but have a custom UITextField that needs to be implemented in code, I am trying to place the text field so that it's 20 pixels above the button, but I am not getting the desired result for some reason. Am I missing something or is this not how you implement it? here's my implementation and output:

```
@IBOutlet weak var buyPointsButton: UIButton!

lazy var cardTextField: STPPaymentCardTextField = {
    let cardTextField = STPPaymentCardTextField()
    return cardTextField
}()
```

In `viewDidLoad`

```
self.view.addSubview(cardTextField)
cardTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: cardTextField, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: buyPointsButton, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 70),
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: cardTextField, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: buyPointsButton.frame.width),
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: cardTextField, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: cardTextField, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 28)
])
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are setting the text field's `.centerY` to the view's `.centerY` ***and*** you're constraining the Bottom of the text field to the Top of the button...

You'll find it **much** easier to work with constraints if you use the more "modern" syntax, and include comments telling yourself what the constraints are - or at least, should be - doing.

For example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.addSubview(cardTextField)
    cardTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
        // Bottom of text field 20-points above Top of button
        cardTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buyPointsButton.topAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        
        // text field Width equal to button Width
        cardTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buyPointsButton.widthAnchor),
        
        // text field centered horizontally to button
        cardTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buyPointsButton.centerXAnchor),
        
        // text field Height equal to 28
        cardTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28.0),
        
    ])
}
```